# VBA Selection.Formula returning "False" instead of "N/A"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using VBA to run a set of data against five "rule" columns stored in another sheet in the workbook. Put simply, I seem to have code which works, but the VBA use of Selection.Formula =  returns "False" when an cell formula would return #N/A or #VALUE. It's critical that I get the error values because it tells the user something different than "False". False should mean that column C (see picture of calculation tab below) doesn't pass the rule. The error values mean that either column B is not found with VLookup in the Rules column or the rule was written incorrectly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Sub Build_Formulas_v2()

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Range("a2", Range("a65536").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 6).Select
    Selection.Value = _
    Evaluate("(""=""&SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2,'Logic Statements'!A:E,4,FALSE),""ZZZ"",""c""&ROW()))")

    End Sub
```

Any help would be tremendously appreciated - my VBA knowledge is still growing and is too basic to understand what I'm up against.

Comment: Use the `Selection.Text` instead of the `.Value`.

Comment: @DavidZemens: `.Text` is  readonly property :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout +1 I thought he was examining/comparing to the error value, not trying to write it.  thx!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Excel 2003. You should never hard code values like `A65536`. You can get undesirable results in xl2007+ as they have `1048576` rows.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Build_Formulas_v2()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Offset(0, 6).Formula = _
        "=SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2,'Logic Statements'!A:E,4,FALSE),""ZZZ"",""c""&ROW())"

        '~~> Uncomment the below in case you want to replace formulas with values
        '.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Offset(0, 6).Value = .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Offset(0, 6).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Or if you do not want to use `.Offset`, then you can directly address `Column G`

```
Sub Build_Formulas_v2()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("G2:G" & lRow).Formula = _
        "=SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2,'Logic Statements'!A:E,4,FALSE),""ZZZ"",""C""&ROW())"

        '~~> Uncomment the below in case you want to replace formulas with values
        '.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Offset(0, 6).Value = _
        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Offset(0, 6).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer this is very helpful. Unfortunately, it is still not accomplishing the result I'm after.

It is properly giving me #N/A results, but it is not evaluating the formulas. I want it to evaluate the formula above but also return #N/A if appropriate.

If I use

        ""="&SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2,'Logic Statements'!A:E,4,FALSE),""ZZZ"",""C""&ROW())"

I still get the same result I started with - no #N/A values. Any tweaks?

Comment: Let me clarify further: the VLOOKUP is actually pulling a formula which I then want to evaluate, such as: AND(LEN(C2)=10,OR(LEFT(C2,2)="57",LEFT(C2,2)="13")). That's the formula I need to evaluate, which the VLOOKUP is pulling from the other sheet.

Comment: Yes, if I put the = in front of it. I tested these formulas as cell formulas before transferring over to the VBA code. When the code with you gave me (which does work great) writes the formula to the cell, it is without the "=" in front, so it's just a text string, not a formula. Does that make sense?

Comment: `it is without the "="` Um that is strange because my code, puts the `=`

Comment: Yes it does! It puts the "=" and therefore Excel calculates the SUBSTITUTE function. But then I want it to also calculate the formula that results AFTER it performs the substitution. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: can you paste the exact excel formula here.

Comment: This is what the code you gave me inputs into the actual cell:
AND(LEN(C2)=10,OR(LEFT(C2,2)="57",LEFT(C2,2)="13"))

Comment: One more thought: Could we paste special - values only and insert "=" beforehand? Maybe this extra step would evaluate the new function?

Comment: So basically `B2` has `AND(LEN(C2)=10,OR(LEFT(C2,2)="57",LEFT(C2,2)="13"))` ?

Comment: Almost. B2 has
`AND(LEN(ZZZ)=10,OR(LEFT(ZZZ,2)="57",LEFT(ZZZ,2)="13"))`
That's why I need the `SUBSTITUTE`; these logic rules are written in an environment where we don't have a cell reference to use.

Comment: so you want to evaluate B2 first and then the rest of the formula?

Comment: Yes. I want to perform the `SUBSTITUTE` function first, then once the substitution is complete I have the complete formula that I want evaluated, namely `AND(LEN(ZZZ)=10,OR(LEFT(ZZZ,2)="57",LEFT(ZZZ,2)="13"))`. But the VBA code is just inputting that formula into the cell and it's not treating it like a formula. I feel like this should be so simple but I'm not getting to the next step.
Your help, by the way, is **VERY** appreciated!